# How to set up AWS Trusted Advisor alert for Service Limit warnings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cli

All I want in life is for AWS to shoot me an email when any of Trusted Advisor's Service Limits go to WARN or ERROR status. I've checked their guides, tried chatting with support and no one can get that to happen, so I'm reaching out here.

## Use Case

We spin up a lot of EC2 instances and CloudFormation stacks and everything uses lots of resources. Somehow we always hit a limit we didn't know about in the middle of a validation sprint and end up blocked for an hour while AWS takes their sweet time bumping our limits. I'd like to set up some kind of event to **email devops when one of the Service Limits is close to being reached**. I am alright with it checking as infrequently as once a week, but would prefer once a day if that kind of granularity is possible.

#### Attempts

I tried setting up a CloudWatch Event, but the only option I could get was to email us when the Service Limits were *refreshed* - which is useless, because then you're already in there manually looking at it and there's no point in an email.

#### Options

Support told me there's no default functionality for this inside of AWS, so I'm looking for either custom event options, or I will also accept something leveraging Jenkins2 and the AWS CLI if that is a possible route. If Jenkins is the way to go it doesn't need to send an email - I'd probably have it slack our devops channel, if that changes the answer any.

Answer (score 7):

That's on my backlog but still on early stage, I just surfaced the idea, so here's are my findings so far:

[Using Trusted Advisor as a Web Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/trustedadvisor.html)

Mainly: 
[Poll a Trusted Advisor Check for Status Changes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/trustedadvisor.html#getcheckstatus)

This documentation example can be implemented with aws cli with the [`support`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/support/index.html#cli-aws-support) subset of commands and targetting the 'us-east-1' region, you'll then have to filter on the `region` field in the `TrustedAdvisorResourceDetail` structure part of the list.

I still didn't had time to write a script to poll the API (I would aim at ruby with the AWS SDK per our usage more than a shell script to group the requests).

Hope this help getting started even if that's not really a complete answer.

Courtesy of Romeo Ninov: For a  recap of which options is available for which account type you can check [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/trustedadvisor/) site

Comment: Tensibai, for most interesting options you need Business or Enterprise type account...

Comment: @romeo I edited again for the form, keeping the credits as much as I can I think